# linux redhat + exclude RPM from yum update

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

is it possible to **exclud**e RPM from yum update

**for example**

the yum update command should bring the Linux to be with the highest patches  level

but in some case we want to install all full patches but except for example **iptable RPM**

is it possible?

my second question

dose **yum list** is the command that show exactly the RPM that **yum update** intend to install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible to exclude packages while update. Example,

   `yum -x 'iptable*' -x 'php*' update`

> From `man yum`,
>   −x, −−exclude=package
>   Exclude a specific package by name or glob from updates on all repositories. Configuration Option: exclude

2. `yum list` just provides all available and installed packages and
   will NOT list the RPM that yum update intend to install. If you want to check use `yum list updates` (also check [`man yum` list options](http://man.cx/yum(8)#heading5) for more
   details).